# probability of sequential events

Tags: probability

Imagine we have 2 slots that can be sequentially occupied (2nd slot only after the 1st one) by (let's say) squirrels. Each slot has its own probability of being occupied: 1st slot can be occupied with p1= 0.1 and the second with p2= 0.6.
I am wondering what is the probability of these 2 slots being occupied.
If we have only 2 squirrels than this probability is p1*p2.
I have troubles to figure out what this probability will be if there are N squirrels.

Answer (score 0):

This is textbook conditional probability. The probability of N squirrels is given by product(p-1,...,p-n). Now if you're asking about how to obtain the probability for each successive slot in the sequence, you'll need to calculate it from the observed distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Product of probabilities will not work for the computing probability for the last slot, because they are not independent. What's the way to derive this disruption?